# Differential of multi variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential

I'm trying to find the differential of the following multi variable function and then use the external definition of gradient in order to find its gradient:
$$
f(\overline{x})=\phi(A\bar{x}) \,,where\,\bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m},\,A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\,,\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} 
$$

My calculation is:

let $u=Ax$, then $$df\underbrace{=}_{definition\,of\,differential}\frac{\phi(u)}{du}\cdot du\underbrace{=}_{substitution+chain\,rule}\frac{d\phi(Ax)}{dAx_{1}}\cdot dAx_{!}\cdot\underbrace{Adx_{1}}_{inner\,derivative}+\ldots+\frac{d\phi(Ax)}{dAx_{n}}\cdot dAx_{n}\cdot\underbrace{Adx_{n}}_{inner\,derivative}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\frac{d\phi(Ax)}{dAx_{i}}\cdot dAx_{i}\cdot\underbrace{Adx_{i}}_{inner\,derivative}\underbrace{=}_{inner\,product\,definition}\langle A^{T}(\nabla\phi(Ax))^{T},dAxdx\rangle
$$

What's my mistake here and how should it be done correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Converting to indices makes things easier. Let $A=A^j_{\:i}$ (rows then columns) and let $$u^j = \sum_i  A^j_{\:i} \: x^i$$ so that

$$ f(x) = \phi(Ax) =\phi(u) \text{ .}$$ By definition of the differential, we have that

$$df = \sum_k \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} dx^k $$ and thus

$$ df = \sum_k \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^k} dx^k \text{ .}$$

By the chain rule, we know that

$$\dfrac{\partial \phi(u(x))}{\partial x^k} = \sum_j\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u^j} \dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} $$ therefore

$$ df = \sum_k \sum_j\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u^j} \dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} dx^k \text{ .}$$

Looking more closely at $\dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k}$, the product rule gives us that

$$ \dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} = \dfrac{\partial (\sum_i A^j_{\:i} \: x^i)}{\partial x^k} = \sum_i\bigg(\dfrac{\partial  A^j_{\:i} \:}{\partial x^k}  x^i +  A^j_{\: i}\dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^k}\bigg)$$ where $\dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^k} $ equals $1$ or $0$ depending on if $i=k$ thus

$$\dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} = \sum_i\bigg(\dfrac{\partial  A^j_{\:i} \:}{\partial x^k}  x^i +  A^j_{\: k}\bigg) \text{ .}$$

We can now substitute this into $df$ so

$$ df = \sum_k \sum_j \sum_i\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u^j}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial  A^j_{\:i} \:}{\partial x^k}  x^i +  A^j_{\: k}\bigg) dx^k \text{ .} $$

If you are using a cartesian coordinate system, the the components of $df$ are the components of the gradient. In other words, the gradient can be indexed as

$$ (\nabla f)_k =   \sum_j \sum_i\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u^j}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial  A^j_{\:i} \:}{\partial x^k}  x^i +  A^j_{\: k}\bigg)  \text{ .}$$

Comment: When you write $$x^{k}$$ you mean $$x_{k}$$?

Comment: @weaver20 yes, I am indexing using superscripts and subscripts. Note that they are not quite interchangeable unless we are in cartesian coordinates (with caveats of course). A geometrical vector is best expressed with superscripts but for the purposes of this question, you may of course pretend the superscripts are subscripts.

Comment: @weaver20 for example the first thing I wrote $$ u^j = \sum_i  A^j_{\:i} \: x^i $$ just means the matrix multiplication $u=Ax$.